# using Geany IDE on Ubuntu

Tags: compiling, binary, geany, raspberrypi

I am new to Linux, I would like to try image processing using C. I am planning to use Geany.

My questions are:

1. Can Geany compile these programs?
2. Can I convert the same to a binary file to load it on to raspberry pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, lets quote the webpage:

> Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features.

What this means? That Geany is first a text editor later an IDE, it won't compile a thing by itself, so you may need the libraries and headers to start compiling.

IDE by wikipedias definition:

> is a software application that provides comprehensive facilities to computer programmers for software development. An IDE normally consists of a source code editor, build automation tools and a debugger. Several modern IDEs integrate with Intelli-sense coding features.

So, Geany will just allow you to see the code very pretty, saves you from going to the terminal and executing the compiler and help you to debug the code.

For your second question, I recommend you to got to [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) for in deep information, but I was able to find you this:

> [...] all of the Linux binaries being used by Raspbian OS has been written using the C programming language. [...] In this blog post, I wrote two types of source code. The first one is a simplified function to compile C source code into a executible for the Raspberry Pi.

Source: http://www.element14.com/community/blogs/mirandasoft/2013/05/09/linux-simplified-cross-compiling-raspberry-pi-binaries-using-c-programming-language

Comment: Thank u very much.. I am looking for the compiler or better the cross compiler for the same. I am looking for other option to program using C.. i mean some other platform and cross compile the same..

Answer (score 0):

If we read the doc, you can see that Geany is able to compile C programs if a compiler is installed on the system. 
You will also need some tools that are indicated in the documentation.

http://www.geany.org/manual/#source-compilation

Comment: Thanks for the help. Iam reading trough the website. I am looking for cross compiling options too.